# Duplicating Sheet with values only

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet named "live". It is a mixture of formula and data. I want to run a script that will create a duplicate, named by a cell within the "live" sheet to create a new sheet.

The below code works but I want it to be values only, not formula based:

```
function Duplicate() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
ss.getSheetByName('Live')
    .copyTo(ss)
    .setName(ss.getSheetByName('Live')
        .getRange(2, 22)
        .getValue())
}
```

Comment: Create a new sheet> ``getValues()`` from old sheet and ``setValues()`` > delete old sheet.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don’t know how to do that.